# VirtualBox Under CentOS vboxdrv not loaded

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, linux-kernel

I am a newcomer with linux. I have a little problem with linux.

Whenever I try to open [start] virtual box, I get this error and do not know how to fix

```
VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is 
a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Re-setup the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. Users of Ubuntu or Fedora should install the DKMS package at first. 
This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles 
the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

I can not see Windows partition either, I am dual booting with Windows XP Home.

Could you please show me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` command?

Comment: I tried to do that but it is not successful. it had the letter [sudo] password for beowulf:
 beowulf is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
 .

Comment: Ok, you need to run this command as root, so use `su` if you haven't added yourself as a sudo user.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it is the first time I use Linux so I can not understand how to this pronblem. Would you please show me more detail to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Switch to root user

```
su root
```

Install the Linux kernel driver

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```